# Mostrar ListItem de un select en C# y asp.net?

Tags: c#, select, asp, dropdownlist

Tengo el siguiente select con valores llenados a mano:

```
         <asp:DropDownList ID="TipoEquipo" runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem Selected="True" 
         Value="" Text="Selecciona..."> 
         </asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem 
         Text="Profesional"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Base"></asp:ListItem>                
         </asp:DropDownList>
```

Ese select lo guardo por ejemplo en Equipo.WidgetElegido donde Equipo es la tabla de labase de datos donde tiene que guardarlo.

Luego tengo una tabla donde muestro algunos de los valores que quiero sacar de esa tabla, de esta forma:

```
 for (i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
    {

  celda = new TableCell();
   celda.Text = lista[i].WidgetElegido;
   fila.Cells.Add(celda);

   }
```

Sería algo asi donde lista es la lista de todos los equipos. Hasta aquí está bien, me muestra la tabla el valor que he guardado para cada equipo. Lo que no logro hacer es que en vez de una palabra en la tabla, me muestre el mismo select que tengo en asp con el valor seleccionado, para poder cambiarlo en el momento desde la misma tabla.

Debería usar el selector.Items.Add? Como?

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano!!

```
              celda = new TableCell();

                DropDownList selector = new DropDownList();
                selector.ID = "select" + lista[i].Codigo;
                selector.Attributes.Add("onchange", "GuardaTipoLiga('select" 
               + lista[i].Codigo + "', " + i.ToString() + ");");
                for (j = 0; j < lista.Count; j++)
                {
                    selector.Items.Add(new 
            ListItem(lista[j].WidgetElegido));
                }

                if (lista[i].WidgetElegido.Length > 0)

         selector.Items.FindByText(lista[i].WidgetElegido).Selected = true;
                else
                    selector.SelectedIndex = 0;
                tipo_liga = tipo_liga + lista[i].WidgetElegido + "+";
                celda.Controls.Add(selector);
                fila.Cells.Add(celda);
```

Comment: Indica siempre el código completo, ya sea método, función evento etc. Como lo estás mostrando es de dificil lectura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es añadir un objeto del tipo **`DropDownList`** a cada celda de tu tabla, con el elemento correcto seleccionado.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
{

    celda = new TableCell();

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    DropDownList dropDownList = new DropDownList();
    // CREAMOS UN DropDownList Y LO CARGAMOS CON LOS DATOS
    for (var x = 0; x < lista.Count; x++)
    {
        dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(lista[x].WidgetElegido, ""));
    }
    // SELECCIONAMOS EL ELEMENTO ACTUAL.
    dropDownList.Items.FindByText(lista[i].WidgetElegido).Selected = true;
    // AÑADIMOS EL DropDownList A LA CELDA.
    celda.Controls.Add(dropDownList);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////

   fila.Cells.Add(celda);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Me ha ayudado bastante. Bien, tengo un problema. Eso solo me despliega en la tabla los 2 valores si previamente se ha insertado dicho valor del select en alguna fila. Me explico, si yo hago un insert de una fila con Profesional, en el desplegable de la tabla solo me muestra profesional y no base porque no ha sido insertado previamente. Edito mi post de arriba con lo que he modificado. He cambiado un poco el código, porque dicho valor lo debo de guardar luego mediante un botón.

Comment: Te aconsejo crees una nueva pregunta. Y Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta.

Comment: Por supuesto. Siempre valoro, me haya ayudado o no la respuest. Solo tomarse un tiempo es suficiente. Lo hacía para no crear otro hilo, pero así haré. Muchas gracias de nuevo!!

Comment: Te propuse lo de la nueva pregunta para que describas mejor tu problema, ampliando las explicaciones todo lo posible y con un código más completo. Así será mas fácil que te respondan.